# How can I sort by year, month and season all at the same time?

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

So, I'm using this code to help sort a "Date" column in my table:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"monthYear-pre": function ( a ) {
    return new Date('01 '+a);
},

"monthYear-asc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
},

"monthYear-desc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ?  -1 : 0));
}
} );
```

It works fine with dates such as "Jul 2012" but it won't cooperate with dates that have just the year (e.g. "2004) or have a season (e.g. Spring 2008). Also, if I've got "unknown" I'd like it to always appear last.

Any ideas? I think making the seasons analogous to a month would be the easiest way to sort that (e.g. Spring=Mar, Summer=Jun, Autumn=Sep and Winter=Dec) but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Thank you!

P.S. I'm a novice - I kind of understand what the second two strings are doing, but the first "monthYear-pre" is a mystery. If anyone would like to explain then I'd be thrilled.

Comment: The first one is turning "Jul 2012" into "01 Jul 2012", parsing the latter as a Date, and sorting on it.

Comment: But how would you decide whether Winter is before or after Summer?  Presumably "March 2012" < "July 2012", but "December 2012" > "July 2012", and yet parts of both March and December are in Winter, while July is clearly Summer.

Comment: Heh, that's a good point. I'd probably just take an unilateral decision and split the year into four: MarAprMay, JunJulAug, SepOctNov and DecJanFeb. Using the first month of those groups would determine the order (so winter after summer). I think people will cope!

Comment: You do realize, though, that only about 10 days of winter are in December, and around 80 are in January - March?  But still, where I am (Southern New England, United States), December **feels** like winter and March **feels** like spring.  I'm just wondering if your requirements are entirely thought out here.

Comment: Hmm. The table lists papers/talks given at events. Most of them have a month, but some don't. And some are listed as being from a series of events that took place (for example) in "Autumn 2007". I don't think there's a need for vast degree of accuracy in this instance, so I'm happy to go with what I wrote above. In any case, Wikipedia has spoken: "In the UK, meteorologists consider winter to be the three coldest months of December, January and February" :p

Comment: That's my usual take on winter too.  Still it leaves two thirds of winter in the beginning of the year, and only a third at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
"seasonYear-pre": (function() {
    var seasons = /\s*(winter|spring|summer|fall|autumn),?\s*(\d{4})\s*/,
        matchedMonths = {winter: '02-01', spring: '05-01', 
                         summer: '08-01', fall: '11-01', autumn: '11-01'}
    return function(a) {
        var match = seasons.exec(a.toLowerCase());
        return new Date(match[2] + "-" + matchedMonths[match[1]]);
    };
})();
```

This places winter at the beginning of the year, but you can change the canonical dates in the list above as you please.  It matches strings like "Winter 2012", or "Autumn, 2007".  (The comma is optional, and it's case-insensitive.)  I don't know this table-sorter API.  I modeled this off the "monthYear-pre", but if it needs to be a plain sort method, it would be easy to change.